# re-importing a module into a pycharm console doesn't update the code unless i delete/restart the console

Tags: python, module, console, pycharm

The example shows:

I create a simple module (fibonacci calculator)
I start a pycharm console, import the module, run the function inside console, and it works.
Now I edit some print text in the module.
Go back to the console and run "import fibagain"
The console seems to do this without complaining.
But when I run the fib() function, it is still giving me results from the earlier version. I cannot make the console see the updated version of the fibagain.py file.
If I delete the console and open it again, then 'import fibagain', running fib(3) will give me the latest version.

sorry, but not permitted to post proper image links here.  This address shows the screencapture:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `import` again, you want:

`reload(fibagain)`

This will reload the updated module. (Note: This only works if `fibagain` had been imported some time earlier)

Comment: What if a `from fibagain import fib` statement has been used?

Comment: for python3 it is `import importlib; importlib.reload(inputs)`

Comment: I just found this thread, but I have the same question as @GerasimosPanagiotakopoulos. Any hints?